# VBA Excel 2007 Security warning when Closing with Task manager

Tags: excel, vba, protected, taskmanager, security-warning

In Excel 2007 I Create file and macro (vba), I protected workbook using password 
and to avoid Security warning when closing file through icon red (X) and reopen file and after save my data and indeed, the problem is solved

**Steps**

1. to avoid Security warning (code problem solved is down )
2. Closing file with red icon (X)
3. Reopen file
4. Save my work
5. close and reopen
6. work fine

**But window Security warning arise when Closing file with Task manager and next reopen file, code down not working**

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="blabla"
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="blabla"
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```